# EM.next_tick with recursive usage

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

```
# Spawn workers to consume items from the iterator's enumerator based on the current concurrency level.
def spawn_workers
  EM.next_tick(start_worker = proc{
    if @workers < @concurrency and !@ended
      # p [:spawning_worker, :workers=, @workers, :concurrency=, @concurrency, :ended=, @ended]
      @workers += 1
      @process_next.call
      EM.next_tick(start_worker)
    end
  })
  nil
end
```

I read this part of code from EM interator which is used by EM-sychrony#fiberd_interator.

I have some basic idea of Eventmachin, but I'm not very clear about this kind of recursive usage of next_tick, could any one give me a explaination about this plz?

In my opinion, it's just like a loop while it is handled by EM, not "while" or "for". Am I right? And why this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a recursive call, think of it as "scheduling a proc to happen a moment later",

EventMachine is basically an endless loop that does stuff scheduled to happen in the next iteration of the loop (next tick),

Imagine next_tick method as a command queueing mechanism,

spawn_workers method schedules the start_worker proc to happen on the next iteration of the event loop.

In the next EM loop iteration `start_worker` proc will be ran and a `@process_next.call` will happen which I assume spawns the worker and thus it happens that the first worker is instantiated, the command

```
      EM.next_tick(start_worker)
```

schedules the same block to happen in next iteration of the EM loop until all workers are spawned.

This means that, for example, if 8 workers need to be instantiated, one worker at a time will be spawned in next 8 ticks of the event loop